# What causes a JavaScript structure to fail in a live version but work in testing?

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8 on two servers, both with the exact same ColdFusion version and the same settings.

We are creating a structure in a CFC and passing it to the browser using the toScript() function.  The resulting JavaScript on the web page looks like this:

```
TrackingInfo = new Object();
TrackingInfo["child_catalog_id"] = "";
TrackingInfo["ipaddress"] = "63.123.41.14";
TrackingInfo["parent_catalog_id"] = 1642;
TrackingInfo["session_id"] = 30000390;
TrackingInfo["referral"] = "";
TrackingInfo["useragent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) G    ecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";
TrackingInfo["querystring"] = "";
```

Later in the page, in JavaScript, we pass the TrackingInfo structure (ABOVE) to the same CFC -- but a different function -- using CFAJAXPROXY like this:

```
var jro = new JS_SessionTracking();
jro.InsertSessionTrackingFunction(TrackingInfo);
```

In the CFC, the InsertSessionTrackingFunction function accepts the structure and enters it into the database,

```
<!--- INSERT SESSION TRACKING FUNCTION --->
<cffunction name="InsertSessionTrackingFunction" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="TrackingInfo" required="true">
    <cfset LOCAL.TrackingInfo = ARGUMENTS.TrackingInfo>
    // DATABASE STUFF HAPPENS HERE
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

In our development and stage sites, this works flawlessly, tested in many machines and many browsers. It works as designed and desired.

When we move the code to production, every aspect of it works with the exception of the very last function (InsertSessionTrackingFunction). Our server refuses to process the JavaScript passed to the CFC from the web page. Firebug shows NO errors. The true value is NOT returned.

What might cause the CFC to not like the structure passed to it in the LIVE setting but work perfectly fine in the development setting?

Also, I tried using the ColdFusion function serializeJSON() to format the structure before passing it the page. It outputted to the page like this:

```
LOCAL.TrackingInfo = serializeJSON(LOCAL.TrackingInfo); // serialize the structure

TrackingInfo = "{\"CHILD_CATALOG_ID\":\"\",\"IPADDRESS\":\"63.173.41.14\",\"PARENT_CATALOG_ID\":1642,\"SESSION_ID\":30000390,\"REFERRAL\":\"\",\"USERAGENT\":\"Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko\\/20100101 Firefox\\/10.0.2\",\"QUERYSTRING\":\"\"}";
```

I passed the structure to the function and used the deserializeJSON function to parse it:

```
<cfset LOCAL.TrackingInfo = deserializeJSON(LOCAL.TrackingInfo)>
```

Still, this function works perfectly in development and staging, but fails in production.

Please give me some ideas as to why this might be happening and how I might rectify the problem.

**UPDATE**

I took Jake Feasel's advice and added `<cfset var LOCAL = {}>` in the head of each function, to ensure that values weren't floating around. While it seems to be a good habit in CF8, this didn't solve the problem.

The code below works just fine in production and in our live environment. No changes to the CFC were needed to make this work. ColdFusion simply will not allow that structure to be passed into the function on that server.

```
<script>
  <cfoutput>
        #toscript(TrackingInfo.SID, "SID")# 
        #toscript(TrackingInfo.parent_catalog_id, "Parent")#
        #toscript(TrackingInfo.child_catalog_id, "Child")#
  </cfoutput>

  // CREATE JAVASCRIPT OBJECT
  var jro = new JS_SessionTracking();
  jro.InsertSessionTrackingFunction(SID,Parent,Child); 
</script>
```

Comment: You said there was no error in Firebug, but also no response.  So, you see the Ajax request being sent to the server, with the full JSON body sent with the request, but then you get back a successful (200) response (with no body)?  Things that might be different in production vs. test - different data (maybe a wild character causing a bug?); web server infrastructure differences (reverse proxy causing cache issues?); browser settings (cached pages disabled on test and dev, but not on prod)

Comment: 1) I see the Ajax request being sent perfectly with well formatted arguments. There is NO response.  2) We have tried lots of data, including hard coded stuff that works dev but not production.

Comment: Have you checked the CF/ webserver logs to see if that request actually makes it to the webserver?

Comment: In prod, are you possibly dealing with different domains? As in, the main page is being served by one domain, but the Ajax request actually goes to a different domain (or subdomain, or different port)?

Comment: No, I haven't checked that (I will though).  We do know that the request is making it to the function. If we remove everything from the function and just <cfreturn true>, we get true returned as the response in Firebug. It appears that the function is chocking on <cfset LOCAL.TrackingInfo = ARGUMENTS.TrackingInfo>

Comment: I should clarify, I DO get a "200 OK" in Firebug in the GET line. I do NOT get a "response" tab in the window below the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General troubleshooting places to look for test vs. prod differences:

1. different data (maybe a wild character causing a bug?)
2. web server infrastructure differences (reverse proxy causing cache
   issues; different modules enabled;)
3. browser settings (cached pages disabled on test and dev, but not on
   prod)
4. Additional complexity in server configuration (such as different
   subdomains, or different ports) for hosting the main page and the
   Ajax requests; this would introduce [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
   problems.

However, now that we've eliminated those as possible sources for problems in your specific case....

You say all of your versions of CF are the same, and that you are using CF 8.  However, the "local" scope that you're attempting to use was introduced in CF 9:

http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/6/21/The-New-ColdFusion-LOCAL-Scope

Since (from your comment) this is where you're seeing the error, I suspect this is the issue.

**Update**

One thing that is worth mentioning regarding using LOCAL in CF8 - Using it won't throw an error, but there could very likely be unexpected behavior as a result (possibly, like you are seeing here).

```
<cffunction name="foo">
    <cfset local.bar = "Hello World">

    <cfreturn local.bar>
</cffunction>
```

I've tested the above example in CF8, and it "works" - it doesn't throw an error.  However, what it will do is create a new structure named 'local' in the variables scope for either the request or the component (depending on where the function resides).  It will then be globally available within that context (and potentially persistant if you are caching the CFC instance).  If this is a shared, cached instance of the CFC, it is likely that if you are hitting this from multiple clients at the same time (particularly noticeable if the function is long-running) then you will be overwriting that local variable with each request.  **This is just the sort of problem that would not be readily apparent in development or staging, as there are fewer users hitting the site at once.**  Also, if you are using that same name in different functions, each one could potentially conflict with your running instance, causing who-knows what kind of problems.

The best bet would be to update your function by adding one line:

```
<cffunction name="InsertSessionTrackingFunction" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="TrackingInfo" required="true">
    <cfset var LOCAL = {}>
    <cfset LOCAL.TrackingInfo = ARGUMENTS.TrackingInfo>
    // DATABASE STUFF HAPPENS HERE
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

This will explicitly restrict your local scope to your function.

It's possible you're not seeing the error in firebug because maybe you have some global error handler in place that suppresses CF errors, possibly set to suppress only when in production.

Comment: 1) I am developing a bunch of new stuff using the LOCAL scope (in CF8). I am aware that it's a CF9 feature, but it still works now and it will work perfectly as soon as we upgrade to CF10.  2) I am 100% sure that the two servers are using CF 8,0,1,00000. (This was the first thing I confirmed.)  3) I see many CF errors in Firebug during development. I am stunned that this error is not showing up.

Comment: Please see the update regarding the dangers of using the local scope as you are doing within CF8.

Comment: Jake, thanks for the update. I will give it a try. I appreciate the time you took to put this answer together.

Comment: Rule to live by: before CF9 always var scope.

Comment: @EvikJames your comment about that one line causing trouble still makes me wonder.... Try changing your code to this: `<cfset LOCAL.TrackingInfo = Duplicate(ARGUMENTS.TrackingInfo)>`

Comment: I will try that in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in CF Administrator called "Prefix serialized JSON with", and the default is `//`. If that setting is different on your testing and production systems, it could cause problems.

Comment: In the info I have above, does it appear that setting is used?

Comment: It's used by `serializeJSON` at least, IIRC, don't know about the others. I use a custom CFC to serialize to JSON because I don't like the way CF does it.